# Getting internal error while setting pushnotification on MoonAPNS

Tags: moonapns

I am getting System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: An internal error occurred
when initialize push notification using:
 Dim push = New PushNotification(False,"PushDistributionCertificates.p12", "mypswd")
in MoonAPNS.
This is working fine on desktop but not working on web.
any suggestions, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error.  You need to go to your application pool and make a change:

> application pool - Advanced Settings - Load User Profile - True

Otherwise, .NET cannot open the certificates.